# PHP /AJAX - Update the list at any time when in MySQL appears a new row

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i am trying to make an ajax call to my database and refresh my list that i display from database. Actually what i need is, i have a table with data and i display them using php, now i want to update my list on the page without refresh anytime when in my table is inserting a new row.

sample code

```
foreach($_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL as $_IL_RESULT_DATA){
    echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_name; //display all the name from my table 
}
```

For example:

In my table i have 5 names and you can see them on the page, now somene subit a form and i insert the sixth name in my table, and i want to update my list with the sith name as real time with no refreshing.

I will appreciate any help.

**My complete code**

```php
<?php

session_start();

wp_enqueue_style('il_style_mode');
wp_enqueue_style('il_admin_style_mode');
wp_enqueue_scripts('jquery');



global $_IL_ID;
global $_IL_LIMIT;
global $_IL_TOTAL;
global $wpdb;

$_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL       = $wpdb->prefix . "il_internal_transfer";
$_SESSION['IL_COUNT_ADMIN'] = 1;

require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_request/il_internal_transfer/il_internal_admin/il_internal_transfer_tabs.php");

$_IL_START = 0;
$_IL_LIMIT = 10;

if( isset($_GET['paged']) ){
    $_IL_ID = $_GET['paged'];
    $_IL_START = ($_IL_ID-1) * $_IL_LIMIT;
}

$_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL ORDER BY il_id DESC LIMIT $_IL_START, $_IL_LIMIT");
$_IL_NUM_ROWS_INTERNAL_ALL = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL");

echo '<span class="il_admin_main_title">';
echo '<span>';
echo '<h2>Internal Transfers</h2>';
echo '</span>';
echo '<span>';
require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_request/il_internal_transfer/il_internal_admin/il_internal_transfer_sub_tabs.php");
echo '</span>';
echo '</span>';

echo '<span class="il_admin_transactions_block" id="il_admin_transactions_block">';
echo '<ul id="list">';
if( $_IL_NUM_ROWS_INTERNAL_ALL < 1 ){
    include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_include/il_messages/il_internal_transfer_sorry.php");
}else{
    foreach($_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL as $_IL_RESULT_DATA)
    {
        ?>
        <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_block">

        <form method="post">
            <input type='hidden' name='il_transaction_id' value="<?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_id ?>"  />
            <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw">

                <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_count"><?php echo $_SESSION['IL_COUNT_ADMIN'] ?></span>
                <span class="il_admin_internal_block_raw_full_name">
                    <?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_name ?>
                </span>
                <span class="il_admin_internal_block_raw_from_to">
                    <span><?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_from_mt4 ?></span> <?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_from_mt4_currency ?>
                    <img src="/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_images/il_icons/il_gray_left_icon.png" class="il_arrow_between" />
                    <span><?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_to_mt4 ?></span> <?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_to_mt4_currency ?>
                </span>
                <span class="il_admin_internal_block_raw_email"><?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_email ?></span>
                <span class="il_admin_internal_block_raw_date"><?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_date ?></span>

            </span>

            <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras">
                <?php if( $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_comments === NULL || empty($_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_comments) ){ ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                    <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_comment">
                        <span>Comment:</span>
                        <span><?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_comments ?></span>
                    </span>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if( $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_status == 'approved' ){ ?>

                <?php } else { ?>
                    <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras_status_icon">
                        <img src="/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_images/il_icons/il_green_status_<?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_status ?>_icon.gif" alt="Processing" title="Processing"/>
                    </span>
                <?php } ?>

                <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras_ip">
                    The transaction was done from this ip <?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_user_ip ?>
                </span>

                <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras_ip_select">
                <?php if( $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_status == 'approved' ){ ?>
                    <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras_status_<?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_status ?>"><?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_status ?></span>
                    <img src="/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_images/il_icons/il_green_status_<?php echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_status ?>_icon.gif" alt="Processing" title="Processing" width="20"/>
                <?php } else { ?>

                    <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras_update">
                        <select name="il_status_new">
                            <option>approved</option>
                            <option>waiting</option>
                            <option>rejected</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>

                    <span class="il_admin_transactions_block_raw_extras_update_button">
                        <input type="submit" name="il_status_update" value="update status" />
                        <input type="submit" name="il_delete" value="delete" class="il_admin_transactions_delete_button" />
                    </span>

                <?php } ?>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span class="il_clear"></span>
        </form>

       </span>

        <?php
        $_SESSION['IL_COUNT_ADMIN']++;
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '</span>';


if(isset($_POST['il_status_update'])){
    $wpdb->update(
        $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL,
        array(
            'il_status' => $_POST['il_status_new'],
        ),
        array( 'il_id' => $_POST['il_transaction_id'] ),
        array(
            '%s',
        ),
        array( '%s' )
    );
};

if(isset($_POST['il_delete'])){
    $wpdb->delete( $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL, array( 'il_id' => $_POST['il_transaction_id'] ), array( '%d' ) );
};

$_IL_ROWS_COUNT = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from $_IL_TABLE_NAME_INTERNAL"));
$_IL_TOTAL = ceil( $_IL_ROWS_COUNT / $_IL_LIMIT );

if($_IL_LIMIT < $_IL_ROWS_COUNT){
echo '<span class="il_pagination_block_admin">';
if( $_IL_ID > 1 )
{
    echo "<a href='?page=il_internal_transfer&tab=il_internal_transfer&paged=".($_IL_ID-1)."' class='il_pagination_prev'><span class='il_pagination_prev_icon'></span></a>";
}

echo "<ul class='il_pagination'>";
for( $i = 1; $i <= $_IL_TOTAL; $i++ )
{
    if( $i == $_IL_ID ) { echo "<li class='il_pagination_current'>".$i."</li>"; }

    else { echo "<li><a href='?page=il_internal_transfer&tab=il_internal_transfer&paged=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; }
}
echo "</ul>";
if( $_IL_ID != $_IL_TOTAL )
{
    echo "<a href='?page=il_internal_transfer&tab=il_internal_transfer&paged=".( $_IL_ID + 1 )."' class='il_pagination_next'><span class='il_pagination_next_icon'></span></a>";
}

echo "</span>";
}else{

}

?>

<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    function fetch(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/wp-content/plugins/il_mt4_client_area/il_request/il_internal_transfer/il_internal_admin/il_internal_transfer.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $(data).hide().prependTo("#list").slideDown("slow");
                if($("#list li").length > 15){
                    $('#list li:gt(14)').remove();
                }
                setTimeout("fetch()", 5000);
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have to implement ajax push.

Comment: try server sent events http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Answer (score 0):

Use this JS code for live updating your result. Code will append new result at the top.

**JS CODE**

```
function fetch(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'PATH-TO_FILE',
                    success: function(data) {
                             $(data).hide().prependTo("#list").slideDown("slow");
                        if($("#list li").length > 15){
                            $('#list li:gt(14)').remove();
                        }
                        setTimeout("fetch()", 5000);
                    }
                });
            }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
    <ul id="list">
    <?php
      foreach($_IL_QUERY_INTERNAL as $_IL_RESULT_DATA){
      echo $_IL_RESULT_DATA->il_name; //display all the name from my table 
      } 
    ?>          
    </ul>
```

Comment: i did exactly the same but still is not updating, by the way i am doing this in wordpress in the back office, maybe i am doing something wrong? @vitorio

Comment: May be you should post your complete code here @ionluchian

Comment: i added all my code, please help me where i do the mistake @vitorio

Comment: can u help me please to sort out the problem? @vitorio

Comment: can u please help me to fix the code? i paste here all the code, thanks a lot @vitorio